# Is it possible to run an INSERT inside a SELECT IF in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to run an INSERT query based on the result of an IF query. I tried various syntaxes. I do not want to use a `stored procedure` just a simple query.

This works:

```
select IF ( select sum(price) from my_table ) > 1000, 
    'high price',
    'low price'
);
```

This even works with SELECT queries.

```
select IF ( select sum(price) from my_table ) > 1000, 
    ( select something  ), 
    ( select something else )
);
```

But when I'm trying to replace one of the SELECT's with an INSERT I get a syntax error.

```
select IF ( select sum(price) from my_table ) > 1000, 
    ( select something  ), 
    ( insert something )
);
```

I tested the `insert something` as an independent query and it's working fine.
But is it possible to use it inside the IF expression?

Comment: No, this is not possible.  And you are using an `IF()` *expression*, not an `IF()` *statement*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible unless you are in a procedural block (using `stored procedure`) then you can do like

```
IF(( select sum(price) from my_table ) > 1000)
BEGIN 
    ( select something  );
    ( insert something );
END
```